# Exception when creating ADO.NET SqlConnection

Tags: c#, ado.net, ado

I try to use ADO.NET for executing SQL. But when I create a new `SqlConnection`, I get this exception. I create `.config` file but code still throws error.

I tried to add `app.config` into project with ADO.NET but this did not help.
After that I add into config file `configSections` and `PropertyGroup` but I have previous result.

**Project structure**

[image: Project structure]

FeatureManager.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MssqlManager.Dto;

namespace MssqlManager
{
    public class FeatureManager
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public FeatureManager(string dataSource, string db)
        {
            _connectionString = $@"Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DbName; Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Integrated Security=SSPI; Pooling = true; Max Pool Size = 250; Async = true; Connection Timeout=500";
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<FeatureDto>> GetFeatures()
        {
            const string sqlExpression = @"SELECT f.Id, f.Code, a.FeatureState 
                                         FROM Feature as f
                                         INNER JOIN AdminUnitFeatureState as a
                                            ON f.Id = a.FeatureId";
            var features = new List<FeatureDto>();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var id = reader.GetValue(0);
                        var code = reader.GetValue(1);
                        var state = reader.GetValue(2);

                        features.Add(new FeatureDto
                        {
                            Id = (Guid)id,
                            Code = (string)code,
                            State = (bool)state
                        });
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

            return features;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception stack:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.   > System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception.
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section PropertyGroup. (C:\Projects\Personal\WindowsServerManager\WindowsServerManager\TrainingConsoleUI\bin\Debug\TrainingConsoleUI.exe.Config line 5)
>
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
>          at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
>          at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
>          at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
>          ...
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>          at TrainingConsoleUI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Personal\WindowsServerManager\WindowsServerManager\TrainingConsoleUI\Program.cs:line 18

`App.config` in MssqlManager project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: and how did you get that connection string?

Comment: This connection string I use in another project (same server and db). Server and db name I change before all question.

Comment: The error you're getting now is related to your changes in the configuration file. Nothing to do with Ado.Net. So, let's go back to the original problem. What error were you getting with connection string? Please update question with original error.

Comment: @derloopkat `ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section PropertyGroup.`

Comment: when I create this project I have no config file but I have this exception. After that I tried to create config but problem still thrown

Comment: The error quite clearly states it's a problem in the App.config for the other project though (TrainingConsoleUI).

Comment: this is part of my app.config in TrainingConsoleUI. I don't understand what I need to add into this file:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>`

Comment: I delete PropertyGroup element from App.config in main project and everything worked. Can you explain me why my parent project (MssqlManager) can`t work with PropertyGroup element in App.config?